# PHP update to 5.6 from 5.5

Tags: php, linux, oracle, apache, laravel

I have a problem after I updated my php version to 5.6 from 5.5.

```
OS: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu).
PHP version: 5.5.
Laravel 4.2 with yajra package.
```

I have done the following steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppandrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5.6 php5.6-mbstring php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mysql php5.6-xml
sudo a2dismod php5
sudo a2enmod php5.6
sudo service apache2 restart
```

After that, I checked oci8 extensions:

```
cat /etc/php5/cli/php.ini | grep extension=oci8 => exists
cat /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini | grep extension=oci8 => exists
```

But the following errors occurs when I load my web on the browser:

```
2017-01-09 20:13:54] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined function Yajra\Pdo\oci_connect()' in /var/www/****/vendor/yajra/laravel-pdo-via-oci8/src/Pdo/Oci8.php:449
```

How to solve this problem? Is there any idea, please...

Comment: Is the `yajra` package compatible with php 5.6?

Comment: check if `yajra` library is really included in your laravel project

Comment: Yeap, in my composer.json file:
"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.11",
        "yajra/laravel-oci8": "1.*",

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: It sounds like you need to install the oci8 extension. http://www.syahzul.com/2016/04/06/how-to-install-oci8-on-ubuntu-14-04-and-php-5-6/

Comment: @jww I disagree in this case because the question is about a tool that's primarily used for programming.

Comment: @EJoshuaS - Questions on how to use `apt` and `dpkg`, and how to start and stop services, are usually a better fit at [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).